# How can I count up by a random integer / variable (onclick)?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to simulate a race between a red and a blue dot. A dot wins if it equals or exceeds the value inputted into the text box for distance. As of now, when you click the "Take a step!" button, each dot's location/distance goes up by 1. What I'm not sure how to do is get that location/distance to go up by a random integer, in this case, a random integer from 1 to 3. How can I do that?

Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Dot Race</title>
    <link href="dotrace.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function TakeAStep() {
        var x, y, redcount, bluecount, distance;

        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        redcount = document.getElementById("reddotspan").innerHTML++;
        bluecount = document.getElementById("bluedotspan").innerHTML++;
        distance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("DistanceBox").value);

        if (redcount >= distance && bluecount >= distance) {
          alert("They tied!");
        } else if (redcount >= distance) {
          alert("Red wins!");
        } else if (bluecount >= distance) {
          alert("Blue wins!");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Dot Race</h2>
    <p>
      Race distance: <input type="text" id="DistanceBox" placeholder="0" />
      <br>
      <span class="red">Red dot location:</span> <span id="reddotspan">0</span>
      <br>
      <span class="blue">Blue dot location:</span>
      <span id="bluedotspan">0</span>
      <hr>
      <input type="button" value="Take a step!" onclick="TakeAStep();" />
    </p>
    <div id="OutputDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're getting randoms but never applying them to your dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing the value of `redcount` and `bluecount` but that has nothing to do with `x` and `y`.

I added these lines after `x=` and `y=`. Seems to fix the root cause.

```
document.getElementById("reddotspan").innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById("reddotspan").innerHTML)+x;
redcount = document.getElementById("reddotspan").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("bluedotspan").innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById("bluedotspan").innerHTML)+y;
bluecount = document.getElementById("bluedotspan").innerHTML;
distance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("DistanceBox").value);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Dot Race</title>
    <link href="dotrace.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function TakeAStep()
    {
        var x, y, redcount, bluecount, distance;

        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1  ;
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

        current_red = +document.getElementById('reddotspan').innerText;
        current_blue = +document.getElementById('bluedotspan').innerText;

        redcount = current_red + x;
        bluecount = current_blue + y;

        document.getElementById('reddotspan').innerText = redcount;
        document.getElementById('bluedotspan').innerText = bluecount;

        distance = parseFloat(document.getElementById('DistanceBox').value);

    if (redcount >= distance && bluecount >= distance) {
        alert('They tied!');
    } else if (redcount >= distance) {
        alert('Red wins!');
    } else if (bluecount >= distance) {
        alert('Blue wins!')
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Dot Race</h2>
        <p>
            Race distance: 
                <input type="text"
                       id="DistanceBox"
                       placeholder="0"> 
    <br>

    <span class="red">Red dot location:</span> <span 
    id="reddotspan">0</span>
    <br>
    <span class="blue">Blue dot location:</span> 
    <span id="bluedotspan">0</span>
    <hr>
        <input type="button"
               value="Take a step!"
               onclick="TakeAStep();">
    </p>
    <div id="OutputDiv"></div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. When you were using the ++ operator, you were modifying the current state of the innerHTML to just add one. Instead, you need to set it equal to the new value.

You should also use Number.parseInt so it parses it to a number explicitly. Otherwise, if you do "0" + 1, it will result in "01".

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Dot Race</title>
  <link href="dotrace.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function TakeAStep() {
      var x, y, newRedNumber, newBlueNumber, distance;

      x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
      y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
      newRedNumber = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('reddotspan').innerHTML) + x;
      newBlueNumber = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('bluedotspan').innerHTML) + y;

      document.getElementById('reddotspan').innerHTML = newRedNumber;
      document.getElementById('bluedotspan').innerHTML = newBlueNumber;

      distance = parseFloat(document.getElementById('DistanceBox').value);

      var outputText = "";

      if (newRedNumber >= distance && newBlueNumber >= distance) {
        outputText = 'They tied!';
      } else if (newRedNumber >= distance) {
        outputText = 'Red wins!';
      } else if (newBlueNumber >= distance) {
        outputText = 'Blue wins!';
      }
      document.getElementById('OutputDiv').innerHTML = outputText;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Dot Race</h2>
  <p>
    Race distance:
    <input type="text" id="DistanceBox" placeholder="0">
    <br>

    <span class="red">Red dot location:</span> <span id="reddotspan">0</span>
    <br>
    <span class="blue">Blue dot location:</span>
    <span id="bluedotspan">0</span>
    <hr>
    <input type="button" value="Take a step!" onclick="TakeAStep();" />
    <div id="OutputDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
Math.round(Math.random()*3);
```

Math.random() returns a random number between 0 and 1.
Multiply by 3 to get 3 as highest number.
Round.

Comment: This actually has something to do with the error, is just not a complete answer

Comment: Agreed, but this in itself wouldn't have solved the core issue which was that he was not updating the values. Edited my comment regardless.